# What type of graph is $y=1/(x^2)$

Tags: graphing-functions

Does this count as a reciprocal graph or am I mistaken? The graph looks like an exponential where x >= 0 although the equation clearly suggests otherwise.

Comment: It's not an exponential. It's a power.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint 1:** what the graph of $y=1/x$?

**Hint 2:** $x^2\ge0$

> $~~~$[image]

Comment: So it is a reciprocal.

Comment: Thanks for the hints - can't believe I didn't spot that...

Comment: @rodit You can check it by hand , put $x=-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,\dots$ and see what happens